# Overwritten css still being applied

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `bootstrap` to design my webpage. I have overwritten `.row`'s property in the element's style. But it is still showing up.

[image]

As you can see, there is a scrollbar on x-axis in the above image. But when I inspect the element on chrome's dev tools, and uncheck `.margin-right`, it goes away.

[image]

I have inspected every element in dev tools and there is no element which is more than width of the webpage.

I even tried this script,

```
var docWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;

[].forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('*'),
  function(el) {
    if (el.offsetWidth > docWidth) {
      console.log(el);
    }
  }
);
```

suggested here - https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/
and this shows `undefined` in the console. Please help me understand how this is possible. The `margin-right` property already is striked through in dev tools too.

Comment: Post your code here...not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

make your inline css like this:

```
style="margin-right:0px !important"
```

This will work.

Comment: Tried that already. `style="margin:0px !important"`. This doesn't work either

Comment: in your body tag, write this inline styling,
`<body style="overflow-x:hidden">`

I think this will work.

Comment: @mayankjain yep, but bad inline css is a bad practice tho. in case he had other element that need the body to overflow auto.

Comment: agreed, but I am giving him a possible solution to the current problem instead of the general solution.

Comment: That's not really a solution. Just a hack. :(

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you are using bootstrap library.

To apply `row` and its column `system` you need the container. Like this:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
 // here goes the column
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Never ever change bootstrap .row style. It is essentials to put the margin there to adjust space between column.

Comment: Tried this. I used container, it had a fixed width. I made it 100% and the same thing happened again.